# Duplicates in right outer join

Tags: sql

Please help me on fixing the query below,

```
select id, descr from table1 a
right join table2 b
on a.id = b.id
```

the `descr` has been populating null and duplicates.
How to get rid of this duplicates in future?

Comment: Do share your database table structure and data for understanding

Comment: Query is fine. It is producing nulls and duplicates as per nature of `right join`. Please share details of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Maciejg, Actually the query i gave is a informatica flow. The design is to right join a file with a oracle table. Mapping looks identical in both QA and prod environment, with the same source file we are getting proper data in QA. But in prod the same mapping is populating null values in descr column.

Comment: And this is perfectly valid and in line with right join logic. Extend the post with sample data and expected result, so we could help

Answer (score 0):

Using distinct key, it will fetch the only unique one and if you use right and left join it will get null if content is not there, so use only join.